# Image context.restore();

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, clip

Im starting to learn canvas and i just hit my first frustrating situation, im trying to make a clipping mask of a .jpg src in a triangle. Everything looks fine until i restore my context and try to add any other Path...  my clipping mask appears to not exist anymore.

Here is my code :

```
    <script>
function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    if(canvas.getContext) {

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = 'stephgopro2.jpg';

    // triangle coordonate
    context.save();
    context.beginPath;
    context.moveTo(100, 0);
    context.lineTo(0, 100);
    context.lineTo(200, 100);
    context.lineTo(100, 0);
    context.clip();

    imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 300, 170);
    };

    context.restore();
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = '#333';
    context.rect(0, 0, 600, 200);
    context.fill();
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload='init()'>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="200"></canvas>

</body>
```

Can you please help me with that? many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is loaded asynchronously so the context has already been restored before the image is drawn to the canvas. If you update the code as follows you'll get (what I think are) the results you expect:

```
function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        if(canvas.getContext) {

        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.src = 'assets/1.jpg';

        // triangle coordonate
        context.save();
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(100, 0);
        context.lineTo(0, 100);
        context.lineTo(200, 100);
        context.lineTo(100, 0);
        context.stroke();
        context.clip();

        imageObj.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 300, 170);

            // Restore the context and continue drawing now the image has been drawn
            context.restore();
            context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = '#333';
            context.rect(0, 0, 600, 200);
            context.fill();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks, you are the man ! i just had to put the second path over the triangle to see the image and now i can add everything after my restored context.

Comment: Excellent. Glad I was able to help.